# Cannot add layer to canvas using jCanvas

Tags: jquery, jcanvas

I'm using jCanvas to paint on a HTML `canvas` element. First I initialize a x * x table, with each cell holding a canvas:

```
function init(size) {
            // Adding the board table to the body
            $("#content").append("<table class=\"board\">");

            for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
                $(".board").append("<tr>")
                for(j=0; j<size ; j++) {
                    $(".board tr:last-child").append("<td class=\"square\">");
                }
            }
            // Setting size to match width or height, whichever i smallest
            var h = $("#content").height();
            var w = $("#content").width();
            var rez = (w > h) ? h : w;
            var cSize = rez / size;
            $(".board td").append("<canvas width="+cSize+" height="+cSize+" />");
            $(".board").css("width",rez);
            $(".board").css("height",rez);

            // Drawing icons on the board
            var c = $("canvas");
            var icns = new Array(11);
            for(i=0; i<11; i++)
                icns[i] = "svg/"+ params["hvor"] +"/"+ (i+1) +".svg";

            for(i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(icns.length-1));
                var icn = icns[rand];
                icns.splice($.inArray(icns[rand], icns), 1);
                $(c[i]).drawImage({
                    source: icn,
                    height: cSize,
                    fromCenter: false
                });
            }
        }
```

This works fine, and the images gets drawn on the canvas. I then try to add a layer with a new shape (it has to be removed later, that's why I'm using a layer).

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var h = $(this).height() -2;
var o = h / 3.5;
var t = h / 10;

$(this).children("canvas").addLayer({
    method: "drawLine",
    strokeStyle: "#5cfe15",
    strokeWidth: t,
    x1: o, y1: o*2,
    x2: h/2, y2: h-o,
    x3: o*3, y3: o-t
});
});
```

That's when I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addLayer'`. if i just use `drawLine()` in stead of `addLayer()` it actually draws the line, so the object is clearly a canvas.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems to have been a certain degree of pebkac involved. I was running v. 4.0.1 of jCanvas in stead of 5.0, which I ought to be.
Thanks to quicksilver at #jquery on freenode for the brainwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using jCanvas v5.0, since it introduced the addLayer() method for jQuery collections (that is, $.fn).

-Caleb

Comment: Exactly, as stated in my own reply to myself above. Thanks for a great framework btw :)